# Why atob and btoa has no different in use?

Tags: javascript, base64

Definitely I read about `atob()` and `btoa()`, The `JavaScript` `Base64` decode and encoding function in [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding).

But in use, I made a mistake *but* everything worked well and it is weird to me. see the following code:

```
const en = btoa('amer');
const de = atob(en);
```

Absolutely `console.log(de)` show the `"amer"`. but I made a mistake:

```
const en = atob('amer'); 
const de = btoa(en);
```

Surprisedly, `console.log(de)` show the `"amer"` again!! I can't understand why! The `atob()` method is for decoding, I used it as an encoding function but it works, and then the `btoa()` function decodes the result of this mistake and returns `"amer"`! While I expect `de` must be a wrong and different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In these APIs, for mnemonic purposes, the "b" can be considered to stand for "binary", > and the "a" for "ASCII". In practice, though, for primarily historical reasons, both > the input and output of these functions are Unicode strings.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html/webappapis.html#base64-utility-methods

```
console.log(atob("testString")) // µë-JÚâ
console.log(btoa("µë-JÚâ")) //testString==
console.log(btoa("testString")) // dGVzdFN0cmluZw==
console.log(atob("dGVzdFN0cmluZw==")) // testString
console.log(atob("dGVzdFN0cmluZw")) // testString, even works with no ==
```